# Low Variables causes php 7 warnings in ee 3.1

Tags: php, low-variables, ee3

I get some errors when using Low Variables in EE 3.1 with php 7.

[image: Screenshot from errors]

I don't have the issue when using php 5.6. So I'm using that. But it would be nice to use php 7.

Is there any road map for making Low Variables compatible with PHP 7?

Comment: Haven't tested LV with php7 yet. I'll put that on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no roadmap for making LV—or any other Low add-on—compatible with PHP7.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this! (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/changelog)